# Antminer s9 for mining!

Tags: mining-pools, mining-profitability, mining-hardware, mining-reward, antminer

1. I am thinking of putting 20 antminer S9 and start mining Will it be profitable as I have calculated monthly electrical bill of 2500$(USD) in my country??
2. Also  should i be mining alone or join a pool?
3. At last will it be worth the money and how much should I expect in return?

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51577/how-much-is-enough/51584